# Orchard CMS. Failure to save field added to Menu Part

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have added a text field to the Menu Content Part which is part of Content Menu Item.

When I try to create a Content Menu Item in Dashboard Navigation, the text field is not saved!

However, if I choose to edit the content menu item, after I have created it, and enter a value into the field, this is saved!

Is this a bug in Orchard or have I missed something?
I have tried this with 1.6 and 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue I opened in April.  Please vote on it here:  https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19568